# How to use wordpress settings and session information on a custom page?

Tags: wordpress

I am new in designing applications for wordpress websites. This is my first time when i am creating an application in wordpress environment. I am creating a PHP script **getinfo.php** that will deliver a json object containing information about currently logged in user in wordpress. And for that I need to know the php code to initialize wordpress backend PHP environment.

e.g including a php file or calling a function which will load the user's session information from database of a wordpress website.

e.g. If any basic PHP website which stores information of currently logged in user in $_SESSION variable. For such website i will write following code in **getinfo.php** to get information from user's session.

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
```

What will be the code for acquiring exact same information in wordpress environment?
How to initialize the session object in wordpress?
And how to access it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

wordpress isn't using `$_SESSION` - but you can get the user info through the global `$current_user` object.

the above in wp should look like this:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
    echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
    echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
    echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
    echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
    echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Do i have to include any wordpress .php file to make is_user_logged_in() function available in my getinfo.php file?

Comment: no, this is a global wordpress function that you can use inside your theme's index.php (or custom template file etc.)

Comment: no no. I want to fetch the information from getinfo.php file only and i am going to put a GET request to the same file using ajax. That is why i have to put initialisation code in getinfo.php file. The php execution is going to start from getinfo.php file and going end in the same file only.

Comment: what is getinfo.php and where does it reside inside your wp-folder?

Comment: i can put it in any subfolder, but i think website root directory is a good idea. And the file contains just few lines of php code which identifies currently logged in user and echos the information in json format.

Comment: normally you either add this functionality to your theme or you would create a plugin. don't just put a php file in the root directory.